# Running maven plugins depending on future phase execution

Tags: maven, phase, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm using maven-enforcer-plugin mainly for

```
                        <dependencyConvergence />
                        <requireUpperBoundDeps />.
```

I don't want to run it on "mvn clean" or "mvn test" in order to avoid unnecessary delays for these commands, esp when running unit tests from inside NetBeans, so I added it to the verify phase and it works quite well.

However, I'd like to run it earlier, ie. before any compilation is done, but only if we do more than just tests.... is there any way to do this? In other words: is there a way to execute a plugin inside an early phase depending on whether *another* later phase is planned?

Comment: No. I don't think that's possible. It would be really weird to be able to do that...

Comment: you can achieve it via parametrizing the `skip` element of the enforcer plugin or via profile, but then you would need to activate it (or pass a value,  i.e. `mvn clean package -Dcheck`) when invoking maven, hence you would tell the future to maven. By default, it can't know about it

Comment: If you run the tests inside of Netbeans will the life cycle being triggered by Netbeans ?